# Why does no interpolated line appear when I use the 3D Analyst to generate a elevation profile in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, dem, interpolation, 3d-analyst

I want to generate an elevation profile based on a DTM with ArcMap 3D Analyst but the program does not show the the interpolated line.

I did the following steps:

- Opening 3D Analyst, adding a Digital Terrain Model (tif)
- Interpolate Line -> drawing a line on my map -> double-click
- At this point a line should appear on my map but nothing is happening
- If I click on Profile Graph ArcMap shows a error message which requests me to select a 3D line
- I can´t select a line because the line which I already created is not displayed on my map

Does anybody know a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't working because you're using a .tif as your "functional surfce" or the surface 3D analyst is trying to analyze. After a quick review (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/an-overview-of-the-3d-analyst-toolbox.htm) looks like .tif is not a supported functional surface. Though your .tif may be called a DTM, ArcMap will not recognize it as such because of its raster format. I'd suggest converting your .tif into a terrain, TIN, or native ESRI raster.
This documentation is old but thorough: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Digitizing_3D_shapes